# Connected subgroup of a topological group.

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups

If $G$ is a connected topological group, and $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$, such that 
$G/H$ is simply connected, does it follow that $H$ is connected?

(In the particular class of cases I have in mind, $G$ is compact, and $G/H$ is homeomorphic to a convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. )

Answer (score 1):

At least if $G, H$ are Lie groups, there is a [long exact sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group#Long_exact_sequence_of_a_fibration)

$$\dots \to \pi_1(G/H) \to \pi_0(H) \to \pi_0(G) \to \pi_0(G/H)$$

which shows that the answer is yes. In fact, the long exact sequence shows that if $G/H$ is contractible then the map $H \to G$ is a weak homotopy equivalence, and hence if $G, H$ are Lie groups it is a homotopy equivalence by [Whitehead's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem).